# Django complex query without using loop

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models such that

```
class Employer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=False,blank=False)
    eminence = models.IntegerField(null=False,default=4)

class JobTitle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=False,blank=False)
    employer= models.ForeignKey(JobTitle,unique=False,null=False)

class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=False,blank=False)
    jobtitle = models.ForeignKey(JobTitle,unique=False,null=False)
```

I would like to list random 5 employers and one job title for each employer. However, job title should be picked up from first 10 jobtitles of the employer whose number of people is maximum.

One approach could be

```
employers = Employer.objects.filter(isActive=True).filter(eminence__lt=4 ).order_by('?')[:5]

for emp in employers:
    jobtitle = JobTitle.objects.filter(employer=emp)... and so on.
```

However, loop through selected employers may be ineffiecent. Is there any way to do it in one query ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written such code block and it works. Although I loop over `employers` because I have used `select_related('jobtitle')`, I consider it doesn't hit database and works faster.

```
employers = random.sample(Employer.objects.select_related('jobtitle').filter(eminence__lt=4,status=EmployerStatus.ACTIVE).annotate(jtt_count=Count('jobtitle')).filter(jtt_count__gt=0),3)

jtList = []
for emp in employers:
    jt = random.choice(emp.jobtitle_set.filter(isActive=True).annotate(people_count=Count('people')).filter(people_count__gt=0)[:10])
    jtList.append(jt)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is! Check out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

`select_related()` tells Django to follow all the foreign key relationships using JOINs. This will result in one large query as opposed to many small queries, which in most cases is what you want. The `QuerySet` you get will be pre-populated and Django won't have to lazy-load anything from the database.

I've used `select_related()` in the past to solve almost this exact problem.

Comment: Could you look at my answer ? I am not sure about the solution actually.. thanks